# How do I delete text that has Track Changes comments without deleting the comments?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, versioning

In Microsoft Word 2013, we are using Track Changes to add comments to the document, and then marking each comment as resolved once it is addressed. However, when the required action is to delete some text and the comment was made on that text, the comment gets deleted as well. This prevents us from seeing that the comment that prompted the deletion.

Is there any way to delete text without deleting the associated comment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### How do I delete text that has Track Changes comments without deleting the comments?

- Open the "Track Changes Options" dialog box

[image]

- Change "Balloons in All Markup view show" dropdown from "Revisions" to "Comments and formatting".

[image]

The deleted text will now be shown with "Strike-through" format and the comments will stay visible.

Source [Change options for Track Changes](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Change-options-for-Track-Changes-fee8a93d-9172-42dd-b0f3-e3b39b6c5840)

Answer (score 2):

If you add white space to the text marked for deletion, the balloon comment may remain.

(other answer(s) given only solve the problem if you want to do it through strikethrough. However, many don't want strikethrough, since they need the text to disappear).

Comment: That seems to be a comment to another answer.

Comment: No, it actually precisely answers the problem. I got it from someone answering the same question on another string. It worked for me to solve the problem with MS Word's track changes/comments issue. So if you want to deprive your readers of this helpful answer, go ahead and don't show it. (Hard to believe there are people who actually gestapo answers they know little about.) Feel free to end my status as a contributor.

Comment: @ChrisCorbett I've edited your answer to look more like an answer and less like a comment; it seemed to me to be just about the wording. Also bear in mind because the "best" answers are sorted to the top you need to avoid references like "the answer above" because it might not always be above. "Earlier" or "other" answers do the job just as well.